# Which email services "thread" email conversations into 1 item in the inbox (like Gmail does)?

Tags: gmail, webapp-rec

I would like to have a record of all email services, other than Gmail, that have the following feature: a chain of replies to a single original email are placed together into a "thread" so that all subsequent replies are grouped into just one entry in the inbox. It's a format that mimics online forums, where you click a thread title to see the original post and all the replies. Which email services have this capability?

Comment: I looked at the help center page regarding addressing the closing of a question. I disagree that this question invites "debate, arguments, polling or extended discussion." This question does not solicit comparison between different services. So there is nothing to debate or discuss. Instead, the question is about creating a record of what all the possible options are. I simply wanted to know all the webmail services that have a particular feature: namely, the feature that all email replies to a single original email are "threaded" together into one item in the inbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mozilla-thunderbird with any email, and use this extension: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/gmail-conversation-view/

Comment: Hmm nice! This will be more complicated, since I've never used Thunderbird and will have to install it and set it up to work with the email account. But this sounds like a good approach. By the way, with Thunderbird, all the emails will be downloaded to my computer, won't they? (And disappear from the online inbox?) Isn't that how any email client software such as T-bird works? 

I can't vote up either of these 2 answers but I would if my rep would allow it.

Comment: I don't know a web client like gmail, i search much a long time, with a email cliente like thunderbird, you can configure if download email to you computer and disappear or download and dont disappear (this options is about POP or IMAP protocols)

Comment: Hmmm... I finally installed thunderbird and this extension. It doesn't seem to work quite right. Maybe I didn't set it up correctly? It didn't combine different emails in my inbox into 1 entry, even though those different emails were part of the same "conversation". (They have the same subject.) For instance, I sent an email, received a reply, replied to that reply, then received another reply. I still see both replies to me as two separate entries in Thunderbird, rather than all 4 emails (both sent and received) in 1 thread, which is how it would be in Gmail. Why the difference?

Comment: Oh, I guess it only works like Gmail with new emails. I just tested it out, sending out 1 email from Thunderbird (linked with my GMX Mail account) to my Gmail account, then replying from Gmail back to GMX, then replying from T-bird/GMX back to Gmail, then replying again from Gmail. In T-bird, I now see all 4 emails together in 1 entry or conversation. That is how I want it, just like Gmail. But this extension was not able to collect earlier emails into 1 conversation, emails that were already in the inbox before the extension was installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Hotmail's Conversation View](http://www.pcmag.com/slideshow_viewer/0,3253,l%253D250956%2526a%253D250948%2526po%253D9,00.asp?p=n)

Comment: Oh, interesting! Thanks, I didn't know this. I haven't gone back to Hotmail in a long time. Now, if only there was another service that is not so popular, because I will surely not be able to register the name.lastname@hotmail.com that I want, without adding some numbers or whatever due to how popular hotmail is...

Comment: On the Hotmail sign up page, you have a choice of picking a either a hotmail.com or live.com account & still use it for Hotmail. So you may check if there is live.com user name matching your requirement is available.